# EXCEL VBA using FOR LOOP that will disregard the step +1 LOOP COUNTER

Tags: vba, excel

I am in search of a solution that will disregard or take one step back from the loop counter. Here is my code for better understanding.

```
 Sub DownArrow5_Click()
Dim c As Integer
Dim copyFromRow As Integer

copyFromRow = 1

For c = 1 To 20
   If ActiveSheet.Rows(copyFromRow).Hidden = False And Range("A" & c & "").Value <> "" Then
   'start copy paste
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & copyFromRow & ", C" & copyFromRow & "").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Else
        c = 'disregard the +1 for the loop

   End If
 Next c   
End Sub
```

I can't decrement the counter since it will have a negative (-) result thus returning an unending loop.

**NOTE:** I need to copy and paste 20 UNHIDDEN rows to sheet2. That is why I need to get the Max counter (20). This is just a brief code from what I am working on.

Comment: What does that mean ? What exact behaviour are you expecting ?

Comment: I think you need to give us a bit more context, what are you trying to achieve exactly? I can only think of a trivial answer...

Comment: Guys, im sorry for the little info. Uhmm, I just need the counter to step back if the IF Condition hasn't met since I need the loop and the IF condition to get to the max counter which is 20. I'll edit my question and hope youll get me. :)

Comment: +1 now we're talking :)

Comment: No need to SCREAM, and definitely not INTERMITTENTLY. (Although I imagine it would be difficult to scream the word 'intermittently'.)

Comment: How is that related here? @ZevSpitz.. coz definitely no ones screaming. ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another type of loop:

```
c = 1
Do
    If (condition) Then
        'do stuff

         c = c+1  'increment your counter variable
    Else:
        'presumably do nothing, i.e., "Disregard" the loop.
        ' do NOT increment the counter variable in the Else block
    End If

Loop While Not c > 20
```

Comment: I'll try this sir David.. THANK YOU so much !!! :) as well to you sir @retailcoder.. :)

Comment: @Krynce I think David deserves the *accepted answer* tick mark for guessing it right straight off your original post! - you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, manipulating your loop counter in a `For...Next` loop probably isn't a good idea. Your code snippet isn't clear about *why* you would need to do this, but if you need to use the value of `c - 1` somewhere in your `Else` block, either use `c - 1` (without assigning `c`), or assign `c - 1` to another variable:

```
Sub DownArrow5_Click()
    Dim c As Integer, d As Integer

    For c = 1 To 20
        If (condition) then
            'do stuff here

        Else
            d = c - 1
            'some more stuff here using d

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE**

Now that you have edited your code with more details, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
While c <= 20

    If Not ActiveSheet.Rows(copyFromRow).Hidden _
       And Range("A" & c).Value <> vbNullString Then

        'do your stuff
        c = c + 1

    End If

Wend
```

Note that VB has several loop constructs that can work just as well - and any condition that evaluates to `False` at 20 iterations will do, so just use whatever you find more readable:

```
Do Until c = 21 ' until c = 20 would make it 19 iterations since c starts at 1
   ...
   c = c + 1
Loop

Do While Not c > 20
   ...
   c = c + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I still can get a NEGATIVE d for this code. which is what I am avoiding. I just need to step back or disregard the loop +1 for the counter since I need the IF condition be based by the max counter which is 20. I really hope you get the idea.

Comment: If the value of `c` is going to be between 1 and 20, then the value of `d` is going to be between 0 and 19 - that's how I read "step back". Please consider updating your question with your actual condition code, if that condition can help - seeing the answer David has just posted, it occurred to me that condition might greatly help, especially if it's tightly related to how the loop works.

Comment: @Krynce it's impossible to get a negative value for `d`. You could get a zero-value, but not a negative value.